# How to set image for imageView in different item position in a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created a recyclerview where all registered pets in my db will be displayed, accompanied by an image that differs depending on the kind of breed the pet is.

Now my problem is that whenever I register a pet in my database the same image shows for every pet registered.

What I did is get the breed of the pet in my database and compare it to a string that I made for differentiating different breeds for the image of each one of them.

So can anyone show how to do this the right way please?

Here is my code for my recyclerview

```
    public class db_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<pet_viewholder>
{
    Context data_context;
    ArrayList<db_getItem> items;
    public db_adapter( Context data_context,  ArrayList<db_getItem> items) {
            this.data_context=data_context;
            this.items=items;

    }

    @Override
    public pet_viewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.reg_view_pet, parent, false);
        return new pet_viewholder(view, data_context, items);
    }
    public void add(db_getItem pet) {
        items.add(0, pet);
        notifyItemInserted(0);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(pet_viewholder holder, int position) {
        holder.pet_name.setText(items.get(position).getPet_name());
        holder.pet_breed.setText(items.get(position).getPet_breed());
        holder.pet_age.setText(items.get(position).getPet_age());
        holder.pet_bday.setText(items.get(position).getPet_bday());
        holder.position=position;

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }


}
```

And here is the code for my Viewholder for displaying the pet image.

```
   public class pet_viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView pet_name;
    TextView pet_breed;
    TextView pet_age;
    TextView pet_bday;
    ImageView pet_image;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<db_getItem> arrayList;
    db_adapter adapter;
    Context data_context1;
    pet_database pet_database;
    Cursor c;
    public pet_viewholder(final View itemView, final Context data_context1, ArrayList<db_getItem> arrayList) {
        super(itemView);
        this.data_context1=data_context1;
        this.arrayList=arrayList;
        pet_name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_pet);
        pet_breed=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.breed_pet);
        pet_age=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.age_pet);
        pet_bday=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.bday_pet);
        pet_image=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pic_breed);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.reg_pet);
        pet_database = new pet_database(data_context1);
        c=pet_database.queryData("select * from pet_registered");
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {

            do {

                String pos=c.getString(3);
                String beagle="Beagle";
                String bulldog="Bull Dog";
                if(beagle.equals(pos)){
                    pet_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.beagle);

                }
                else if(bulldog.equals(pos)){
                    pet_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bulldog);
                }
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do code according to your requirement to **`onBindViewHolder`**

**Note**: onBindViewHolder will called every for time the setting the data for every row.

```
String bread = items.get(position).getPet_breed();

if(bread.equals("breadOne")
{
  holder.pet_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.beagle);
}
else if(bread.equals("breadTwo")
{
  pet_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bulldog);
}
```